Simple Account report returns duplicate Accounts, should be impossible
This is my report definition:

And this is the result, 5 records in total:

How on earth is this possible? If I do a SOQL query with the same condition, I get 4 records. Why is one Account duplicated in the result?
As you can see in the report definition, it is just a report on Accounts, not Accounts + Contacts or other related records.
Also, if I create a new report on Account, and group by record type, the report returns 4 Supplier Accounts.

As this report was so simple, I just created a new report, with exactly the same filters. And this new report shows just four Accounts.
I guess the old report was corrupt, in some way or another.
